# How to find a variable in a hex editor

Tags: c++, arduino, ide, hex-editors

My goal is to be able to change the value of a calibration variable externally (using a hexadecimal editor). I have used the Arduino IDE to develop my code.

The variable, defined as a float, is called corrector and is definded as a global variable before the setup(): `float corrector;`

In the setup() I first define it's value: `corrector = 1.0f;`

Afterwards, I print the hex address where the variable is located :
`Serial.print("\tAddress: "); Serial.println((unsigned int)(&corrector), HEX);`

The address I get is 309, and when I look at this address at the hex editor what I find is a 30, which means a 0 (wrong because I gave the value of 1 to the variable).

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if I am doing well or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how floating point values are represented? If you set a floating point value to `1`, you're not going to find a byte containing `1` anywhere. That's not how floating point values work.

Comment: You can find a full explanation in Wikipedia. It wouldn't make any sense to copy/paste a [huge wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) here, so I'll have to refer you to the article for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've been reading the article and seems to be really complicated to convert the data. I have thought that representing the variable as another type (as a byte for example) could help to see it more clearly.

Comment: I agree: it is complicated.

Comment: yes @AsierMintegia a byte would be much easier to recognize and edit in hex editor

Answer (score 0):

A float value of "1.0f" is represented as four bytes 3f800000 (possibly in reversed order if your platform is little-endian) Since this is a global variable without initializer, its address is very probably the *runtime* address, not the address in the binary.

If you change the definition like this:

```
float corrector = 1.0f;
```

You should be able to find those bytes in your binary at the place where the `corrector` symbol is in your symbol table.